# How to catch Memory Quota exceptions in a heroku worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, heroku

I am using delayed_job to handle my background jobs with heroku.  Occasionally I will overstep my memory allocation and I get stuff like:

2011-11-16T02:41:25+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2011-11-16T02:41:45+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=542M(106.0%)

I would like to elegantly handle this.  Is there a way to find out when I am about to cross my memory limit?

Something like [rack-timeout](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) would be awesome

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a good solution to this, by stealing some code from the [Oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink) gem. In particular this file: [memory_snapshot.rb](https://github.com/noahd1/oink/blob/master/lib/oink/instrumentation/memory_snapshot.rb), Which you should read.  It outlines 4 different ways to messure memory usage

So there is no way to have this on the Rack level, you need to add a memory check during a process that is causing the memory issue (in my case it was building a csv file).

So in that loop it looked something like:

```
  def build_string_io(collection)
    csv_io = StringIO.new
    csv_io << collection.first.to_comma_headers.join(',') + "\n"
    collection.each do |imp|
      csv_io << imp.to_comma.join(',') + "\n"
      check_memory!
    end
    csv_io.rewind
    csv_io
  end

  def check_memory!
    raise 'AboutToRunOutOfMemory' if memory > 400.megabytes #Or whatever size your worried about
  end


  # Taken from Oink
  def memory
     pages = File.read("/proc/self/statm")
     pages.to_i * self.class.statm_page_size
  end

  def self.statm_page_size
      @statm_page_size ||= begin
      sys_call = SystemCall.execute("getconf PAGESIZE")
      if sys_call.success?
        sys_call.stdout.strip.to_i / 1024
      else
        4
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you handling the R14 error? Are you purging memory using `GC`? Are you starting a new worker?

Comment: In my case, it was okay for me to truncate my csv file when i approached my memory limit.  But if i couldn't do that -- I guess I would page through collection.  Hopefully I can avoid using GC.  Be curious how you end up solving it.

Comment: Only way I could think of is to fire up a new worker and terminate the current one. What do you mean "page through collection"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that you need the data which is only available from the logs.

The best approach here will be to use a syslog drain to send your logs to a service like Papertrailapp.com or Loggly - with these services you can set up searches for your R14 error but then receive notifications - Papertrail supports campfire, posts, emails etc where you can handle the error.

We do this exact process posting into a sinatra app also hosted on Heroku where we're looking at the heroku router log entries and the queue= sizes or for backlog too deep errors and then automatically scaling our applications when demand requires - because the syslog is almost realtime our apps are essentially self aware.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that when you receive this error you've already been dumped out of the Ruby process and the Heroku platform is handling the error.  No amount of begin, rescue, end will help you here.

In terms of seeing it coming, you could potentially look at the amount of memory free by running something like:

```
memory = `free -m`
```

You can then parse these results to get yourself a meaningful memory state.  However, I'm not sure what you can do with this information.

(Remember a dyno is just a unix box, and you can run arbitrary system commands with Ruby by wrapping commands in backticks)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this system call, idea taken from this script [memory_snapsot.rb](https://github.com/noahd1/oink/blob/master/lib/oink/instrumentation/memory_snapshot.rb) from the oink gem:

`system("ps -o vsz= -p #{$$}")`

This way you may have some ideas about the memory increase and where it can be produced in your code